# Client / Server / Client Communication via sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, lego-mindstorms

I have 3 devices which are connected via a bluetooth PAN network.

- **Device 1**: Server - The Server is in my case an EV3 LEGO Brick == a
  ROBOT!
- **Device 2**: Remote - The second device (Android APP) should be
  used to control the actions of the Device 1
- **Device 3**: Frontend - The
  third device should display the chosen actions (Android)

The possible communication method is bluetooth and a socket connection in JAVA. I can already control DEVICE 1 from DEVICE 2 - but the commands are not relayed to DEVICE 3. This is the code which I am using for my server:

Main

```
        try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket( 1111 );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
        }
        // new thread for a client
        new RelayThread(socket).start();
    }
```

RelayThread THREAD

```
public class RelayThread extends Thread {
protected Socket socket;
BufferedReader bufferedReader;

public RelayThread (Socket clientSocket) {
    this.socket = clientSocket;
}

public void run() {
    Singleton motors = Singleton.getInstance();
    InputStream inp = null;
    BufferedReader brinp = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        inp = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inp, "UTF-8");
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);           

        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            String command= bufferedReader.readLine();
            if ((command== null) || command.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT")) {
                socket.close();
                return;
            } 
            else {
              // do ROBOT actions

                /*
                 * SERVER ACTIONS
                 */
                    // notify the other client of the delivered LINE
                    out.writeBytes(command);
                    out.flush();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using TCP-Client as my DEVICE 3 right now - but it doesn't show any text when I send commands via DEVICE 2. How could I realize my project - and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to deliver message first to server and server send it to other client or clients. so, does your server read message from device-2 and deliver it to device-3  ? I dont see it in your code

Comment: that's why I use "out.writeBytes(command);" in the RELAY-Thread

Comment: out and in are use same socket. it means, they use same client. so in your case, if device-2 sends command, device-2 gets command again. you need to keep Relay threads in a list in your server, and iterate them, and deliver coming message from any client to all client. this would be solution for you. look at my answer

Comment: Hi Adem, I can't see an answer from you, except the comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is for your server. Creating a list of all connections

```
List<RelayThread> clients = new ArrayList<RelayThread>();
while (true) {
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
        }
        // new thread for a client
        RelayThread relay = new RelayThread(socket,this);
        relay.start();
        clients.add(relay); 
   }
```

and a method to send message to other clients

```
public void sendCommand(String command, RelayThread source){
  for (int i=0;i<clients.size();i++){
     if (clients.get(i) != source) {
        clients.get(i).sendCommand(command);
     }
  }
}
```

and, constructor of RelayThread to keep Main

```
Main main;
public RelayThread (Socket clientSocket,Main main) {
    this.socket = clientSocket;
    this.main = main;
}
```

and, a sender message in RelayThread

```
public void sendCommand(String command){
    out.writeBytes((command+"\r\n").getBytes()); // I suggest you add a parser charachter, like \r\n. then client can understand message ends
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code - I can already see where it's heading. However I'm not able to create a list of clients. The line  "RelayThread relay = new RelayThread(socket,this).start();" throws the following error "RelayThread relay = new RelayThread(socket,this).start();"

I guess I need to adapt the constror of RelayThread, or?

Comment: Thanks! Up until now I was initializing my server in the STATIC main method of my class "main" ... however this seems to work badly with the "This" reference. I'm going to try to refactor the code.

Comment: I have refactored my code and got it to work :). I just need to figure out how to hold a connection open on my clients. Basically the list of clients fills up really fast ( every command which I transfer from DEVICE 2 is another client in the server)